# How does the construction of a hydrophone differ from a microphone?

Tags: acoustics

Both devices serve the same function, but a hydrophone must do it in a denser medium. What's the major difference in design? (besides being water-proof!)

I'm asking about the relevant physics driving design in this case. I think a physicist would be able to explain this so that a good mechanical engineer would be able to design microphones for use alternately in air, underwater, submerged in honey, or at 20,000 feet.

Comment: Not knowing anything about it, I'm talking off the cuff here, but I believe that forces will be higher for a given frequency and displacement amplitude (though that is a function of the sound being louder); perhaps that calls for more robust materials.

Comment: Also, this runs dangerously close to the kinds of engineering questions that we discourage. It might help to explain the context of the question.

Comment: It's ok to think like an engineer (sometimes) :)

Comment: The question is not if it is OK to think like an engineer (all the best people do), but if it is OK to *post* like an engineer on Physics SE.